# Bash Regex Accepts [Number], but i want only Number accepted

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have some Problems and i dont know what causes them. In my Script (bash) i want to ask with "if" if my $1 is a number. Only 0-9 Digits and optinal "-".
When i make

```
`if [[ "$1" -eq "$1" ]]`
```

or

```
 if `([[ $1 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]`
```

Both times i can make

```
`./myscript [number]`
```

or

`./myscript number*`

and the number got accepted. But of course i dont want [number] to be a number as parameter. Only Numbers without any other symbols, brackets or other stuff

Can Someone tell me where is my Problem? I only want to understand why the bash acts like this. I dont want some complete code snipped that solve my Problems. Only some ideas was causes the Problem
Greetings

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 4):

I guess in current directory you have a file named number. Please see log below:

```
[arturcz@home xxx]$ ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 arturcz arturcz  60 Jun  5 16:27 .
drwxrwxrwt 16 root    root     580 Jun  5 16:27 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 arturcz arturcz  88 Jun  5 16:24 number.sh
[arturcz@home xxx]$ cat number.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo Number
else
    echo Not number
fi
[arturcz@home xxx]$ ./number.sh 1
Number
[arturcz@home xxx]$ ./number.sh [1]
Not number
[arturcz@home xxx]$ ./number.sh 1*
Not number
[arturcz@home xxx]$ touch 1
[arturcz@home xxx]$ ./number.sh [1]
Number
[arturcz@home xxx]$ ./number.sh 1*
Number
[arturcz@home xxx]$
```

If you want to avoid parameter to be interpreted and expanded by bash, put in in single or double quotation marks:

```
[arturcz@home xxx]$ ./number.sh '1*'
Not number
[arturcz@home xxx]$ ./number.sh '[1]'
Not number
```

Comment: Thank you! Problem was that [1] seems to be a Test in the Bash. By making it "[1]" it gives me not a number. Thank you very much!

Comment: `[1]` is a pattern, just like `*.txt`, that is subject to pathname expansion.